# Quantum field theory free particle field operators

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I am reading the book Abrikosov methods of quantum field theory in statistical physics.
I got stuck at some derivation of the field operators for the free particle.
The reasoning in the book is as follows. First particle field operators are defined as

$
\Psi(\xi)=\sum_{i}\varphi_{i}(\xi)a_{i}
$

$
\Psi^{+}(\xi)=\sum_{i}\varphi^{*}_{i}(\xi)a^{+}_{i}
$

where $\varphi_{i}(\xi)$ are wavefunctions of a particle in state i. $\xi$ is a combination of
spin and position coordinates. $a_{i}$ and $a^{+}_{i}$ are the ladder operators.
The field operators satisfy the same commutation/anticommutation relations as the ladder operators

$
[\Psi(\xi),\Psi^{+}(\xi^{'})]=\delta(\xi-\xi^{'})
$
and $[\Psi(\xi),\Psi(\xi^{'})]=0$ and $[\Psi^{+}(\xi),\Psi^{+}(\xi^{'})]=0$.

Then a free particle wavefunction (without spin) is introdcued

$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}e^{i\mathbf{p}\mathbf{r}}
$

where $\mathbf{p}$ is the momentum and $\mathbf{r}$ is the position.

The field operator $\Psi(\xi)$ in the Schroedinger picture for the free spinless particle is

$
\Psi(\mathbf{r})=\sum_{\mathbf{p}}e^{i\mathbf{pr}}a_{\mathbf{p}}
$

The Hamiltonian is
$
H = \sum_{\mathbf{p}}n_{\mathbf{p}}\epsilon_{0}(\mathbf{p})
$

where $n_{\mathbf{p}}=a^{+}(\mathbf{p})a(\mathbf{p})$ is the number of particle operator and $\epsilon_{0}(\mathbf{p})$ is
the energy of a particle with momentum $\mathbf{p}$.

Now the field operator in the Heisenberg picture is introduced as
$a(t)=e^{iHt}ae^{-iHt}$.

This is done for the free particle field operator as

$
\tilde{\Psi}(\mathbf{r},t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}
\sum_{\mathbf{p}}e^{i\sum_{\mathbf{p}^{'}}\epsilon_{0}(\mathbf{p}^{'})n_{\mathbf{p}^{'}}t}
a_{\mathbf{p}}e^{-i\sum_{\mathbf{p}^{''}}\epsilon_{0}(\mathbf{p}^{''})n_{\mathbf{p}^{''}}t}
e^{i\mathbf{pr}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{\mathbf{p}}a_{\mathbf{p}}e^{i(\mathbf{pr}-\epsilon_{0}(\mathbf{p})t)}
$

This is exactly where I got stuck. Because I don't understand the
mathematical identity or what "trick" was used to obtain the result after the second equal sign in the last equation.

Comment: [This?](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/creation-anhilation-operator-exponential-commutator-relation.793052/post-4982952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Use Heisenberg Equation of Motion:
\begin{align}
\ic\,\totald{a_{\bf p}\pars{t}}{t} & = \bracks{a_{\bf p}\pars{t},H} =
\expo{\ic Ht}\
\underbrace{\bracks{a_{\bf p},H}}
_{\ds{\epsilon_{\bf p}\,a_{\bf p}}}\expo{-\ic Ht} =
\epsilon_{\bf p}\,a_{\bf p}\pars{t}
\\[5mm] \implies &
a_{\bf p}\pars{t} = a_{\bf p}\expo{-\ic\epsilon_{\bf p}\,t} 
\end{align}